# Return rows with differents sum values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table above. If I sum the balance value I'll have 23.47.

```
Date        num (pk)    document    supplier    debit       credit      balance    
2016-12-06  4302458     26933       SUPPLIER_1  4,35                    4,35       
2016-12-06  4302456     26933       SUPPLIER_1  19,12                   19,12      
2016-12-13  4330098     27023       SUPPLIER_1  5,79                    5,79       
2016-12-13  4330096     27023       SUPPLIER_1  25,45                   25,45      
2016-12-13  4330095     27023       SUPPLIER_1              1.157,00    -1.157,00  
2016-12-13  4330591     223130      SUPPLIER_1  1.115,76                1.115,76   
2016-12-13  4330588                 SUPPLIER_1  10,00                   10,00      
2016-12-19  4342835     27108       SUPPLIER_1              1.294,00    -1.294,00  
2016-12-19  4342838     27108       SUPPLIER_1  6,47                    6,47       
2016-12-19  4342836     27108       SUPPLIER_1  28,47                   28,47      
2016-12-22  4366603     223841      SUPPLIER_1  1.259,06                1.259,06   
2016-12-26  4371509     27200       SUPPLIER_1  14,61                   14,61      
2016-12-26  4371511     27200       SUPPLIER_1  3,32                    3,32       
2016-12-26  4371508     27200       SUPPLIER_1              664,00      -664,00    
2016-12-29  4376366     224598      SUPPLIER_1  646,07                  646,07
```

I'm trying to select the rows that the sum of balance are 23.47. In this example the would be these lines?

```
Date        num (pk)    document    supplier    debit       credit      balance    
2016-12-06  4302458     26933       SUPPLIER_1  4,35                    4,35       
2016-12-06  4302456     26933       SUPPLIER_1  19,12                   19,12
```

I tried to use `HAVING CLAUSE` but the return wasn't correct.
I tried with a `PGSQL function` too, but didn't work.
Is there any way to select this correctly?

Comment: This is equivalent to "find a maximal subset of numbers whose sum is zero".  I'm pretty sure that is NP, if not NP-complete.  It is not suitable for SQL.

Comment: Linoff, what does NP mean?

Comment: . . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP_(complexity).

Answer (score 1):

im not sure if this is the cleanest way without writing a procedure but it will work. this joins the table to its self using a created column as a join.

```
SELECT 'join' as link, a.Date, a.num, a.document, a.debit, a.credit 
FROM test a

INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 'join' as link, a.Date, a.num, a.document, a.debit, a.credit FROM test a
)b

ON 'join' = b.link
WHERE a.debit + b.debit = 23.47
```

Comment: So, I think the best way will be writing a procedure, because I have others values from others suppliers, both in debit or the credit but I'm focusing in just one slice. I've tried to this example, but I don't know if I'm wrong but, the result bring me a row not expected:[link](http://i.imgur.com/3R7Bm5L.png) I think we are in the correct way, but, not yet.